# Validate input field with readonly mode in amp

Tags: amp-html

**What's the issue?**

I have two input field on my form. i create different validation for each input which reason i use custom-validation-reporting="show-first-on-submit" . My first input is destination and second input is a calendar. when a user submit form without the date i wanna show a validation message to user which i able to show perfectly .
But my issue is i get the cursor pointer on my second/calendar input which i actually wanna avoid because it is a date field and i don't want to user to type on date field and i wanna make it readonly.

If i put readonly there my custom validation for second input does not work.

What could be the possible solution for it

I am creating the scene here on codepen
https://codepen.io/sayalok/pen/yqXoab

**How do we reproduce the issue?**

If this is a feature request you can use this section to point to a prototype/mockup that will help us understand the request.

**What browsers are affected?**

All browsers

**Which AMP version is affected?**

1531800879103

```
<div class="home-alert-msg" visible-when-invalid="valueMissing" validation-for="search">
    <span>Please enter your destination</span>
</div>
<div class="start_date_err_msg home-alert-msg" visible-when-invalid="valueMissing" validation-for="startDate">
    <span>Enter your trip dates.Search Without Date</span>
</div>
<form method="get" action="https://google.com/" target="_top" class="p2 form" id="form" custom-validation-reporting="show-first-on-submit"> 
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="form-grid">
            <div class="form-item city-state">
                <input placeholder="Where do you want to stay?" name="search" type="text" id="search" required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="date_start" placeholder="Check In" id="startDate" required on="tap:lb.open">
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="date_end" placeholder="Check Out" id="endDate" required on="tap:lb.open" readonly>
    <amp-lightbox id="lb" layout="nodisplay">
        <div class="align-content-center">
            <amp-date-picker type="range"
                id="drp" on="activate: lb.open;deactivate: lb.close;"
                locale="en" format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                first-day-of-week="<?= $this->start_day ?>"
                mode="static" layout="fixed-height"
                height="430" start-input-selector="#startDate"
                end-input-selector="#endDate" open-after-clear>
            </amp-date-picker>
        </div>
    </amp-lightbox>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="subscribe-button" id="subscribe-button-id" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

codepen url : https://codepen.io/sayalok/pen/yqXoab

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and there is a GitHub issue open to address this. 
Please see : https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/17687